# Javascript Date string constructing wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Hi I am trying to construct a javascript date object with a string, but it keeps contructing the wrong day. It always constructs a day that is one day behind. Here is my code

```
var date = new Date('2006-05-17');
```

The date i want to get is

```
Wednesday May 17 2006 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

But instead I get

```
Tue May 16 2006 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: What browser/version?

Comment: you'll notice that 17:00 + 7:00 = 0:00 the next day ;)

Answer (score 12):

When you pass dates as a string, the implementation is browser specific.  *Most* browsers interpret the dashes to mean that the time is in UTC.  If you have a negative offset from UTC (which you do), it will appear on the previous local day.

If you want *local* dates, then try using slashes instead, like this:

```
var date = new Date('2006/05/17');
```

Of course, if you don't have to parse from a string, you can pass individual numeric parameters instead, just be aware that months are zero-based when passed numerically.

```
var date = new Date(2006,4,17);
```

However, if you have strings, and you want consistency in how those strings are parsed into dates, then use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
var m = moment('2006-05-17','YYYY-MM-DD');
m.format(); // or any of the other output functions
```

Comment: Actually, the dashes are only part of the story.  If I add " 00:00" to the time, it is no longer UTC (because of the space).

Comment: Very interesting, since the ISO8601 spec allows for *either* the `T` or a space separator.  Nice find.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens is that the parser is interpreting your dashes as the START of an ISO-8601 string in the format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ", which is in UTC time by default (hence the trailing 'Z').

You can produce such dates by using the "toISOString()" date function as well.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp

In Chrome (doesn't work in IE 10-) if you add " 00:00" or " 00:00:00" to your date (no 'T'), then it wouldn't be UTC anymore, regardless of the dashes. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prepending zero from "05"

Comment: Perhaps, but what do you do in December then?