# New date to string shows as day before because of time zone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

How can I display a date to behave like that day regardless of the users time-zone?

```
>>> new Date('2013-09-17')
Date {Mon Sep 16 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)}
```

I'm trying to use the jquery datepicker formater, however when I pass the date object it's off by a day.
How can I make sure that the users timezone is disregarded?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Javascript Date string constructing wrong date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774293/javascript-date-string-constructing-wrong-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I split the string and passed them as parameters for my expected result.

```
>>> d = '2013-09-17'.split('-');  new Date(d[0],d[1]-1,d[2]);
Date {Thu Oct 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)}
```

Comment: You forgot to subtract 1.  The months are 0-11 when passed that way.